# ERROR in Failed to compile entry-point angular-font-awesome (es2015 as esm2015) due to compilation errors

Tags: angular

While executing the `ng serve` command I am getting the error below after updating angular version 8 to 9:

```
0% compiling
Compiling angular-font-awesome : es2015 as esm2015

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.07 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 677 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 168 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 2.25 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 342 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-08-20T18:45:45.144Z - Hash: accfc9d111ebf6532cd5 - Time: 4333ms

ERROR in Failed to compile entry-point angular-font-awesome (es2015 as esm2015) due to compilation errors:
node_modules/angular-font-awesome/dist/angular-font-awesome.js:3968:26 - error NG1010: Value at position 0 in the NgModule.imports of AngularFontAwesomeModule is not a reference: [object Object]
3968                 imports: [CommonModule],
                            

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

Comment: Having the same issue in on of our projects. Quite strange as other projects don't have the same issue. Will report back if/when I find the fix